# Finding the number of elements in an modified array (duplicates removed)

Tags: c

My array size (in terms of actual number of elements in it visually) will change so I have established an "open-ended" array with a relatively large size that I know it will never exceed.
I would add elements to an array using for loop

```
for(i=0; i<=100; i++) {
    array[i] = i;
}
```

and I would remove duplicates from the array using

```
#define length 100

for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<length; j++)
        {
            if(array[i] == array[j])
            {
                for(k=j; k < length - 1; k++)
                {
                    array[k] = array[k + 1];
                }

                length--;

                j--;
            }
        }
    }
```

and find the array size using

```
int length = sizeof(setarray)/sizeof(setarray[0]);
```

It seems that after the modification
e.g. : {1 2 4 4 3 5 6 2 1 0} to {1 2 4 3 5 6 0}
the array size seems to stay the same. I was wondering if there is a method to find the array size after modification (i.e: add, remove elements).

Comment: Please be careful with an array loop condition like `i <= 100`, as that will loop over 10**1** elements.

Comment: Also, as any decent text-book, tutorial or class should have taught you, preprocessor directives are not terminated by a semi-colon.

Comment: Furthermore, that `sizeof` "trick" to get the number of elements of an array ***only*** works for actual arrays. Once an array have *decayed* to a pointer (like what happens when passing an array to a function) then all you have is a pointer and the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to.

Comment: Lastly, if you don't know the size of the array at compile-time, why don't you use pointers and dynamic allocation? This will probably also solve what seems to be your problem, as the size of an array is fixed and can never be changed.

Comment: By the way, if you use an array larger than you need, what happens with the elements you don't use? Will they stay uninitialized with possible indeterminate (read garbage) values? Will the be initialized to some default value that will not affect your calculations if used?

Comment: Couple of things I'd like to point: 1) Preprocessors never have ; 2) Never define array with a fixed value when you don't know if you need to store more elements or less. 3) The first for loop will store all unique numbers only then what's the point in checking for duplicates? 4) Like @Someprogrammerdude mentioned, you need to use dynamic memory allocation (malloc, calloc, free) for this purpose using which you can get a pointer for the dynamically allocated memory blocks.

Comment: 5) The modifications (like add, remove) you're doing it on the elements and not the memory blocks. That's why after checking for duplicates, the size of array still remains the same. Usually, for this purpose there are libraries used like Vectors for C++ and ArrayList in Java. I'm not really sure about C. 6) As per the title, "Finding the number of elements in the modified array" you can simple keep a count of duplicates found and subtract it with the number of elements inputted (not the predefined size/ length in this case).